# Get Bun Now button from paypal sdk 2.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios7, paypal

I Just want to know that how can i get Buy Now Button from Paypal 2.0.1 SDK in iphone? is there possible to get Buy Now button from Paypal 2.0.1 in iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Dave from PayPal here.

The PayPal iOS SDK is a native iOS library that can be integrated into any native iOS app.

It does not provide a Buy Now Button.